# Does SQLAlchemy's filer_by function protect against SQL injection?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to use the SQLAlchemy filter_by function, but cannot find an explicit statement that the filter_by function escapes input to protect against SQL injection. Our usage is very simple but obviosuly very sensitive.

```
 self.database.active_session()
        .query(Users)
        .filter_by(
            username=username,
            is_active=1
        ).first()
```

Where can I read more about the filter_by function, or can anyone tell me whether it escapes input?

Comment: SQLAlchemy delegates the quoting of values to the underlying DB-API connector package used by the engine, so the protection is as good as that offered by the connector package.  For example, if your engine url is `mysql+pymysql://user:pass@host/db` then the quoting is done by pymysql.

Comment: You can dig into [sources](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/fc5c54fcd4d868c2a4c7ac19668d72f506fe821e/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L1670) to see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the output for postgresql connection

```
# trying to inject
query = db.query(User).filter_by(username="'user'; drop table user; --"")
print(query)
```

Output

```
SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".created_at AS user_created_at, "user".updated_at AS user_updated_at, "user".username AS user_username, "user".hashed_password AS user_hashed_password, "user".is_active AS user_is_active, "user".is_superuser AS user_is_superuser 
FROM "user" 
WHERE "user".username = %(username_1)s
```

String value passes as param to query, so you are protected from SQL injection.